# How can I set the authentication in my app in Zapier?

Tags: zapier

I'm trying to developer an app on the Zapier Developer Platform and I have troubles in authentication.

I have only an Auth Field: Api Key. I have a Test Trigger called 'test_api_key' with a Polling Url and no Trigger Fields. I followed this example: https://zapier.com/developer/documentation/v2/api-key-action/

When I test the authorization in the section 'Connected Accounts'. I have only 'Success' results. Instead, I would like to get a bad result if the Api Key is wrong. When I call my polling url I get a xml in the response that tells me if the Api Key is wrong or is correct.
Maybe I have to create a 'test_api_key_post_poll' method that reads the xml and return a good or a bad result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want it "automatic" - your server should return a non-200 status code if your API Key is bad. For example - 401.

Or, you'll need to add a `*_post_poll` method in your Scripting to `throw` an error if the JSON/XML says "Bad authentication" or similar.

Comment: Thanks Bryan. It works! Is there a way to display a message without throw an exception, even if the authentication goes well?

Comment: There is not - Zapier handles all the messaging on the happy/success path.

Comment: Hello Bryan, can you please help me with Basic Auth method? Here is my exact question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55665069/zapier-basic-auth-pass-blank-data