# Zapier basic auth pass blank data

Tags: api, basic-authentication, zapier

I have been trying to create an app in Zapier for one of my project. On the very first step, I am doing Authentication where I choose "Basic Auth" method. I have set API URL along with details, however cannot see the expected result and seeing error in my API return value. After debugging, I found that API doesn't get the value I pass thru the Zapier. I have checked the same API in postman and it works, however it only doesn't work thru the Zapier.

Below is even more detail how I proceed, what is expected result and what I am getting:

> Process we're following

1. We have created an App
2. We went to Authentication step, there we have selected “Basic Auth” option
3. Under the Basic Auth, we have configure with setting end point and method is “Post”
4. We have set our field names as Key and as value we have set “{{bundle.authData.password}” and “{{bundle.authData.username}}” in order to field mapping
5. Then came to Step 2 to test the authentication
6. Under the “Test Setup”, we have connected the current Zapier account and clicked on “Test Authentication”

This process doesn’t post any value in parameters. Hope I could explain the issue, please help us to find where we’re going wrong.

> Expected Result

```
{
     "data": {
         "first_name": "Dhaval",
         "last_name": "Parekh",
         "email_address": "dhaval.php@gmail.com",
         "phone_no": "1234567890",
         "user_id": "7oiA****",
         "token_id": "zNkzT***"
     },
     "resend_verification_link": false,
     "status": true,
     "message": "You have successfully Logged in!!"
}
```

> Actual Result

```
{
  "resend_verification_link": false,
  "status": false,
  "message": "The password must contain a minimum of one lower case character. one upper case character, one digit"
}
```

What I understand after spending too much time, is it doesn't send the data with post method and hence I'm getting this issue. While it works fine with the Get Method. So, should I consider that Basic Auth will only with work with "Get" method in Zapier? Or I'm missing any piece to include here?

Please let me know what is missing? Or even I'm going thru the wrong root. I want to create an app in Zapier to allow other apps to connect.

Comment: You should also check your API log in order to confirm that everything is good from your end first.

Comment: can you write into `partners@zapier.com` with a link to your app and we can take a closer look? Sounds like it's a setup issue, but it's hard to diagnose without seeing the app.